# Problems when selecting with multiple filters in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am accessing Mongodb from a meteor application. The collection pages contains a document number, d_number, a page number "page" and some text, called "text", like so:

```
   { "d_number" : "213117-14", "page": 1, "text": "Some text" }
```

Now I want to select a certain page of a certain document number. In the Mongo console I do it like this:

```
    db.pages.findOne({d_number:"213117-14", page:1})
```

which gives me the desired result. However, when accessing it in the helpers.js section of the Meteor app like this

```
      text:function() {
        page = Router.current().params.page;
        d_number = Router.current().params.d_number;
        text = Pages.findOne({d_number:"213117-14", page:page};
        return text;
      }
```

the variable text becomes undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be the type of the page number. In the mongo database, it is an integer, but when getting it from the URL parameters in

```
    page = Router.current().params.page;
```

it becomes a string. Thus, the correct code looks like this:

```
      text:function() {
        page = parseInt(Router.current().params.page);
        d_number = Router.current().params.d_number;
        text = Pages.findOne({d_number:"213117-14", page:page};
        return text;
      }
```